# Elasticsearch java api: how to define fields as you would with _source:[] in dsl

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

in dsl I use _source: [] to define what fields I want returned in the response:

```
{
    "size":100,
    "_source": [ "field1", "field2", "field3", "field4" ]
}
```

but I am having trouble figuring this out with the Java API Transport Client. Below is what I use to construct and call the query, so I am not sure what to use for this.

```
SearchResponse sr = mysvc.getClient().prepareSearch(index)
     .setSize(size)
     .setQuery(getBoolQuery())
     .addAggregation(getAggregationBuilder())
     .execute()
     .actionGet()
```

there is a `.setSource()` that can be used here but it takes a SearchSourceBuilder and I haven't any documentation on how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would be helpful for you:

- [SearchSourceBuilder.html#fields(java.util.List)](https://static.javadoc.io/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/2.3.0/org/elasticsearch/search/builder/SearchSourceBuilder.html#fields(java.util.List))
- [Java High Level REST Client » Search APIs » Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-search.html#java-rest-high-search)

Comment: Thanks I found this very helpful. I somehow missed the javadoc.

Comment: It happens :) I'm glad I could help.